# Pause and Resume CasperJS, PhantomJS Script

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using in PHP the library PhantomJS with CasperJS for automatize a web workflow.

How Can I "Pause" the script, saving all the resource, do something with the content and after resume it?

Example: 
1 - load a website.
2 - get info of the page, exit the script and do your stuff in php for example.
3 - go back to the same page **without reloading it**, and continue javascript and navigation.

Right now I have to reask for the last page, and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pause execution, but you can certainly call your PHP script from CasperJS/PhantomJS through the [Child Process Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/). Save the content in some temporary file using the [File System Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) and pass the temporary filename to the PHP script.